# Can lme4 fit a repeated measures model with unstructured covariance? How does it differ from fitting using gls in nlme?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I recently read this paper by Donohue et al. in Pharmaceutical Statistics (Open access: https://doi.org/10.1002/pst.2285). Mixed model repeated measure (MMRM) analyses are discussed. In particular, one of the base models fit includes time points as categorical fixed effects (e.g., visit 1, 2, and 3 included as fixed effects), and their model adjusts for repeated measures by including no random intercept while allowing for different visit periods to be correlated for each subject, I think, using syntax such as `(0 + Visit_Factor | Subject)`. This is not something I was used to seeing, and it indeed requires some over-ride argument for `lmerControl`, otherwise you get an error. I include a simplified and reproducible example that adapts their Supplemental Code to using the sleepstudy dataset included with lme4:

```r
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
sleep_data <- sleepstudy
sleep_data$Day_Factor <- as.factor(sleep_data$Days)
mod1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Day_Factor + (0 + Day_Factor | Subject), data = sleep_data,
             control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
summary(mod1)
# Similar idea here, but Days no longer treated as categorical in the main fixed effect, but still has the same repeated measures adjustment
# mod1b <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (0 + Day_Factor | Subject), data = sleep_data,
#             control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
```

The output is as follows:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Reaction ~ Day_Factor + (0 + Day_Factor | Subject)
   Data: sleep_data
Control: lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")

REML criterion at convergence: 1559.9

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.09523 -0.21529  0.00571  0.18605  1.45012 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr                                        
 Subject  Day_Factor0 1009.68  31.776                                               
          Day_Factor1 1093.96  33.075   0.75                                        
          Day_Factor2  845.33  29.075   0.48 0.79                                   
          Day_Factor3 1480.94  38.483   0.47 0.75 0.89                              
          Day_Factor4 1778.40  42.171   0.45 0.66 0.70 0.92                         
          Day_Factor5 2648.64  51.465   0.37 0.53 0.50 0.73 0.86                    
          Day_Factor6 3952.24  62.867   0.22 0.31 0.46 0.68 0.75 0.75               
          Day_Factor7 2480.48  49.804   0.50 0.48 0.60 0.60 0.70 0.69 0.71          
          Day_Factor8 3593.10  59.942   0.33 0.40 0.41 0.60 0.75 0.91 0.73 0.77     
          Day_Factor9 4458.02  66.768   0.52 0.55 0.43 0.57 0.72 0.84 0.46 0.66 0.89
 Residual               20.32   4.508                                               
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  256.652      7.565  33.928
Day_Factor1    7.844      5.614   1.397
Day_Factor2    8.710      7.494   1.162
Day_Factor3   26.340      8.761   3.007
Day_Factor4   31.998      9.461   3.382
Day_Factor5   51.867     11.722   4.425
Day_Factor6   55.526     15.121   3.672
Day_Factor7   62.099     10.418   5.960
Day_Factor8   79.978     13.710   5.834
Day_Factor9   94.199     13.541   6.957

. . .

optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0073684 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

**Questions**: I think I understand that they are not simply using a random intercept in the model (i.e., `(1 | Subject)`) because that would imply equal correlation between each observation for a Subject (Day 1 and Day 9 for a given subject have the same correlation as Day 8 and Day 9), and an unstructured covariance assumes less inherently. Is the desired model sensible? Minor convergence issue aside, is this a valid approach to fitting the desired model? Without a random intercept and just adjusting for the repeated measures, it seems somewhat similar to GEE although restricted maximum likelihood is used here.

Using `gls` in the `nlme` package, I tried to fit what I think is an equivalent model.

```r
library(nlme)
mod2 <- gls(Reaction ~ Day_Factor, data = sleep_data, 
            correlation = corSymm(form = ~ 1 | Subject))
summary(mod2)
```

With output:

```
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: Reaction ~ Day_Factor 
  Data: sleep_data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1698.281 1873.886 -793.1405

Correlation Structure: General
 Formula: ~1 | Subject 
 Parameter estimate(s):
 Correlation: 
   1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     
2   0.879                                                        
3   0.791  0.916                                                 
4   0.704  0.873  0.920                                          
5   0.598  0.765  0.773  0.934                                   
6   0.169  0.361  0.316  0.573  0.744                            
7   0.088  0.199  0.241  0.476  0.600  0.726                     
8   0.661  0.679  0.737  0.719  0.731  0.510  0.533              
9  -0.172 -0.066 -0.081  0.157  0.350  0.775  0.683  0.342       
10  0.300  0.376  0.290  0.459  0.607  0.784  0.465  0.535  0.776

Coefficients:
                Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 256.65181 12.341806 20.795320  0.0000
Day_Factor1   7.84395  6.065572  1.293192  0.1977
Day_Factor2   8.71009  7.988673  1.090306  0.2771
Day_Factor3  26.34021  9.503064  2.771759  0.0062
Day_Factor4  31.99762 11.069563  2.890594  0.0043
Day_Factor5  51.86665 15.906888  3.260641  0.0013
Day_Factor6  55.52645 16.666616  3.331597  0.0011
Day_Factor7  62.09878 10.155765  6.114633  0.0000
Day_Factor8  79.97770 18.896844  4.232331  0.0000
Day_Factor9  94.19942 14.604891  6.449854  0.0000

 Correlation: 
            (Intr) Dy_Fc1 Dy_Fc2 Dy_Fc3 Dy_Fc4 Dy_Fc5 Dy_Fc6 Dy_Fc7 Dy_Fc8
Day_Factor1 -0.246                                                        
Day_Factor2 -0.324  0.773                                                 
Day_Factor3 -0.385  0.766  0.856                                          
Day_Factor4 -0.448  0.653  0.662  0.915                                   
Day_Factor5 -0.644  0.494  0.427  0.705  0.845                            
Day_Factor6 -0.675  0.349  0.414  0.658  0.755  0.844                     
Day_Factor7 -0.411  0.341  0.535  0.559  0.640  0.640  0.705              
Day_Factor8 -0.766  0.302  0.303  0.530  0.673  0.901  0.855  0.676       
Day_Factor9 -0.592  0.339  0.261  0.500  0.668  0.862  0.674  0.589  0.910

Standardized residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-2.169606808 -0.510143429  0.004249012  0.529962593  2.711585811 

Residual standard error: 52.36185 
Degrees of freedom: 180 total; 170 residual
```

**Questions**: Why are standard errors different between the `gls()` and `lmer()` fits? Is the model formulation different in some way that I am missing? Why is the estimated correlation matrix within subjects different between the two? Why might one prefer `lmer` over `gls` or even GEE when fitting this particular model?

Here are some other Stack Exchange posts that were a little relevant, but didn't exactly answer my question:

[Which mixed model is closest to GLS with unstructured covariance? Random intercept + slopes or random slopes only?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570520/which-mixed-model-is-closest-to-gls-with-unstructured-covariance-random-interce)

[Which mixed model in lme4 best mimics the unstructured covariance in GLS?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570228/which-mixed-model-in-lme4-best-mimics-the-unstructured-covariance-in-gls)

[Linear mixed model with unstructured repeated measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/581284/linear-mixed-model-with-unstructured-repeated-measures)

Answer (score 1):

We have been working a lot in the past 2 years to fit MMRMs in R. Especially the unstructured covariance model is challenging. I would recommend to give the new R package `mmrm` a try. See https://openpharma.github.io/mmrm/main/ to  get started. With that, in your example you can use:

```r
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
library(mmrm)
sleep_data <- sleepstudy
sleep_data$Day_Factor <- as.factor(sleep_data$Days)
mod <- mmrm(Reaction ~ Day_Factor + us(Day_Factor | Subject), data = sleep_data)
summary(mod)
```

(I just tested this and it works nicely)